# How to using preg_replace php for remove font-family style in string?

Tags: php, css

How to using preg_replace php for remove font-family style in string ?

I tried to use this code , but not work. How can i do that ?

```
<?PHP
if(isset($_POST["submit"]))
{
    $editor = $_POST['editor'];
    $editor = preg_replace("#font-family(.*?)>(.*?);#is", "", $editor);
    echo $editor;
}
?>


<form class="form" method="post" action="" ENCTYPE = "multipart/form-data">
<textarea name="editor" style="margin: 0px;width: 415px;height: 30px;" ><p style="font-family: fantasy; font-size: 34px;">test</p></textarea>
<br>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="OK">
</form>
```

Comment: What is the "#" supposed to do?

Comment: @TigOldBitties `preg_replace` requires a delimiter around the regexp. It can be any character, he's using `#`.

Comment: @Barmar It's still wrong even if it is. I've just never seen it. And what is the "is" at the end? As I said, it doesn't make sense to me, in the context he provided.

Comment: `is` are the modifier flags. `i` means case-insensitive, `s` means that `.` can match newlines.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
font-family.+?;
```

would match to 'font-family: fantasy;' in your case. You can just replace it with empty string. Your regex string makes no sense to me.

Perhaps this will help you understand what is wrong better than i can explain it https://regex101.com/

Looks like you're having some trouble understanding regex.

LE: your code should be.

```
if(isset($_POST["submit"]))
{
    $editor = $_POST['editor'];
    $editor = preg_replace('/font-family.+?;/', "", $editor);;
    echo $editor;
}
```

Comment: Warning: preg_replace(): Delimiter must not be alphanumeric or backslash

Comment: $editor = preg_replace("font-family.+?;", "", $editor);

Comment: You're kidding, right? preg_replace('/font-family.+?;/', "", $editor); read the documentation man.

Comment: How can we get two line text ?